# Joining an Ubuntu VM to microsoft AD and DNS

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-9.10, active-directory

So here's what I'm after:

- Create Ubuntu inside Virtualbox (done)
- Join it to the domain using `net ads join -S example.com -u admin` (done)
- Update the DNS using `net ads dns register` (done)
- Be able to visit the netbios name as defined in smb.conf (lets call it Bob). [Not done]

The problem I am having is that it looks like, even though the machine is now on the AD, and I can browse users in the AD, etc... My network configuration (IP/route tables, etc) are not correct.

For example, my AD server is in the 172 IP range, while BOB is sitting at 10.0.2.15.

The DNS server stores Bob's value as 10.0.2.15, so when I ping it from my workstation at 172, I end up getting no response (obviously it's on a different net).

Bob's route table is configured to deal with 10... range of IP, rather than 172.

I have attempted doing commands such as
`ifconfig eht0 172.16.1.118 netmask 255.255.255.0` and even editing the route tables, but that then makes outbound network traffic imposable.

I'm not really a great network expert here so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your VirtualBox networking set up?  Your addresses are correct if your host is doing NAT.  If you want to be on the same subnet, then you need to change your networking configuration to be bridging.

Comment: Yep, I just wasted a lot of time thinking it was because of something else. You're basically my hero. All I had to do was change the adapter from NAT to bridged.